# How to check if digit is at specific place in combination with other regexes

Tags: java, regex

In a method that uses Pattern.matches, I need a correct regex. The method is supposed to return true if:

- pwd starts with a capital letter followed by three lower case letters
- pwd contains exactly one digit, at position 6 of the string
- pwd contains at least 8 characters

I get the first and last requirement fulfilled but cannot include the second one (only one digit at sixth place).

```
private boolean validPass(String pwd)
{
    return Pattern.matches("^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{3}.{8,}$", pwd);
}
```

How to include this condition "pwd contains exactly one digit, at position 6 of the string" in the method above?

Comment: Your Regex does not match Passwords with length >=8 but with length >`1+3+8=12`!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your Regex has the same problem. replace `{6,}`with `{2,}`to match passwords with length >=8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a changed pattern that works.

```java
public static void main( String[] args ){
    //String original = "^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{3}.{8,}$";
    String s = "^[A-Z][a-z]{3}[^0-9][0-9][^0-9]{2,}$";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( s );
        
    String GOOD_PWD = "PabcO5jjfjj";
    String NOT_LONG_ENOUGH = "PabcO5j";
    String NOT_NUM_AT_6 = "PabcOTTggj";
    List<String> pwds = Arrays.asList( GOOD_PWD, NOT_LONG_ENOUGH, NOT_NUM_AT_6 );

    for( String pwd : pwds ) System.out.println( pwd + ": " + p.matcher( pwd ).matches() );  
}
```

Explanation of `^[A-Z][a-z]{3}[^0-9]{1}[0-9][^0-9]{2,}$`:

- `[A-Z]`: First character should be capital (you had done this already)
- `[a-z]{3}`: Next 3 characters should be small letters (you had done this already)
- `[^0-9]`: One non-numeric character to fill the space till position 6
- `[0-9]`: One digit at position 6
- `[^0-9]{2,}`: Minimum 2 non-numeric characters (2 because we already have 6 till here. Non-numeric because we want digits only at position 6.)

Comment: One small correction: the password should contain a digit only at the 6th place. So you should change `.{2,}$` to `\\D{2,}$`

Comment: Thanks. That's correct. I have edited the answer but in a slightly different way.

Comment: @Wiktor, thanks for editing, but I had retained the `{1}`s on purpose - to show the progression of the total till position 6. **:)** Anyhow, it may have given an impression that that is the way. So, it's fine.

Comment: @SreeKumar The point is not to confuse anyone that `{1}` has any real meaning in regex. Some people start believing this quantifier only allows the whole regex to match a single occurrence of the pattern in the string, and they start posting redundant questions that we have to close again and again.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Agreed. Just in case it wasn't clear, in my earlier reply "So, it's fine", meant that the editing was a good idea, not that having `{1}`s was a good idea.

Comment: Is the leading ^ and ending $ necessary in this case (and in the accedpted answer)?

Comment: `^` is necessary because there is a check on a specific position from the start. We are not searching for the pattern "anywhere within the string", but that the entire string should match the pattern. Therefore, the `^` is necessary. However, you are right, `$` may be omitted. Also, *I usually try to keep the answer as close to the original pattern as possible, unless it comes in the way*, so that the questioner finds it is easier to understand. Hence, the `$` and some other forms, like `[0-9]`, were also retained.

Comment: In my opinion, you are doing just fine with retaining as much working code from the original question as possible. The answer and discussion around this question were so helpful and motivating for me that I read up more on regexes. That's how I came up with the ^ / $ comment. Thanks also for your clarification here.